# Форма поиска постов Ajax c выдачей количества результатов

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Всем привет. Имеется на сайте Wordpress такая функция поиска ajax

```
//поиск ajax
function search_form_ajax() {
        $form = _e('<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
        <input type="search" class="search-input" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Ищите тут..." />
        </form>','search_form_ajax');
        return $form;
}
add_action( 'searchformajax', 'search_form_ajax' );

function search_result_ajax() {
        $result = _e('<div class="search-results"></div>','search_form_ajax');
        return $result;
}
add_action( 'searchresult', 'search_result_ajax' );

function search_update_ajax() {
    $title = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['searchvar'] );
    $the_query = new WP_Query (array( 
                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                    'order'         => 'ACS',
                    'Post_per_page' => '30',
                    's'         => $title,
    ));
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>                                                   
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h4 class="search-title" itemprop="headline"><?php echo _e(get_the_title(),'search_form_ajax'); ?></h4>
                            <div class="search-excerpt" itemprop="articleBody">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                <?php endwhile; else : ?> 
                    Мы ничего не нашли :(
                <?php endif; 
    die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxnews','search_update_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxnews','search_update_ajax');
```

Мне перед выводом результатов поиска хочется вставить их количество. В WP есть соответствующая функция

```
function posts_count() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->found_posts;
}
```

Форма поиска и результат у меня выводится так

```
<div class="search-content">
              <?php search_form_ajax(); ?> 
              <?php search_result_ajax(); ?>
        </div>
```

По идее если между этими двумя экшенами вывести что типа такого

```
<div class="results-count"><?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s result for', '%s results for', $count, 'zeen' ), $count ); ?></div>
```

то должен появиться счетчик постов. К сожалению не знаю как запихнуть в самые верхние функции, функцию `posts_count()`. Не очень силен в PHP. Там еще и нужно подставить переменную цикла the_query, до того, как он закроется. Памагите)))

Comment: Где твой js-запрос через AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После строки

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
```

добавьте ваше

```
$count = $the_query->found_posts;
```

затем, если это

```
<div class="results-count"><?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s result for', '%s results for', $count, 'zeen' ), $count ); ?></div>
```

работает на вашем сайте, можете вставить счетчик перед началом вывода постов, примерно так

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$count = $the_query->found_posts; ?>
<div class="results-count"><?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s result for', '%s results for', $count, 'zeen' ), $count ); ?></div>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```